# Support Vector Regression with High Dimensional Output using python's libsvm

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, regression, libsvm

I would like to ask if anyone has an idea or example of how to do support vector regression in python with high dimensional output( more than one) using a python binding of libsvm? I checked the examples and they are all assuming the output to be one dimensional.

Comment: 'more than one' -> Don't you mean multidimensional then?

Comment: [This](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1820839) seems to describe a method that does what you're looking for, it's fairly recent. Not sure if libsvm can do that though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support Vector Machines as a mathematical framework is formulated in terms of a single prediction variable. Hence most libraries implementing them will reflect this as using one single target variable in their API.

What you could do is train a single SVM model for each target dimension in your data.

- on the plus side, you can train them in // on a cluster as each model is independent of one another
- on the minus side, sub-models will share nothing and won't benefit from what they individually discovered in the structure of the input data and potentially need a lot of memory to store the model as they will have no shared intermediate representation

Variant of SVMs can probably be devised in a multi-task learning setting to learn some common kernel-based intermediate representation suitable for reuse to predict multi-dimensional targets however this is not implemented in libsvm AFAIK. Google for [multi task learning SVM](https://www.google.com/search?q=multi+task+learning+svm) if you want to learn more.

Alternatively, multi-layer perceptrons (a kind of feed forward neural networks) can naturally deal with multi-dimensional outcomes and hence should be better at sharing intermediate representations of the data reused across targets, especially if they are deep enough with the first layers pre-trained in an unsupervised manner using an autoencoder objective function.

You might want to have a look at http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/ for a nice introduction to various neural network architectures and practical tools and examples to implement them efficiently.

Answer (score 4):

libsvm might not be the best tool for this task.

The problem you describe is called multivariate regression, and usually for regression problems, SVM's are not necessarily the best choice.

You could try something like group lasso (http://www.di.ens.fr/~fbach/grouplasso/index.htm - matlab) or sparse group lasso (http://spams-devel.gforge.inria.fr/ - seems to have a python interface), which solve the multivariate regression problem with different types of regularization.